# How can I temporarily disable my MBP's keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, keyboard

I sometimes bring my external keyboard with me on the go and use it with my MBP. I would like to lay it over the macbook's current keyboard without having to worry about it pressing other keys.

**Is there a way to temporarily enable/disable the onboard keyboard?**

Comment: See same question here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341009/disable-the-internal-keyboard-of-a-macbook-pro?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**KeyboardCleanTool**](https://folivora.ai/keyboardcleantool) to lock/unlock the keyboard using the mouse.

[image]

Comment: This also disables external keyboard, which is not what OP wanted

Answer (score 3):

[Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) has an option to automatically disable the built-in keyboard when an external keyboard is connected.

Comment: This is done from the Devices tab in Karabiner: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/configuration/disable-built-in-keyboard/