# Disable MacBook Pro 2018 Mojave Keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, mojave, kernel-extensions

Simply put, I was wondering how I could disable my MacBook's keyboard temporarily.

It used to be possible in earlier versions of macOS by following [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341009/disable-the-internal-keyboard-of-a-macbook-pro). This no longer is the case.

I have a MacBook Pro 2018 on macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: Do you mean something as simple as [KeyboardCleanTool](https://folivora.ai/keyboardcleantool) or do you want something more selective?

Comment: @Tetsujin That is exactly what I am looking for. If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is a quick disabler to, for instance, clean your keyboard without pressing random keys, then there's a lovely bit of freeware called [KeyboardCleanTool](https://folivora.ai/keyboardcleantool) for precisely that purpose.